# How to display two textfields euqal space in single tableview cell with equal width, edges space

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I want to display two textfields in single tableview cell along with some separator between of them both. Those, two textfields has equal space to edges and with the separator. I want to create this in programmatically in tableview cell class in Swift language.

I want this to be fit in all dimension devices.

Note : I am not using autolayout.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use `UIStackViews` as it sounds like a perfect use case for your question.

**Definition of a UIStackView in the Documentation:**

> A streamlined interface for laying out a collection of views in either
>   a column or a row.

It would take care of the resizing behaviour of your views and you could also easily control the margins and the spacing between your elements.
You can use `UIStackViews` with storyboards or programmatically depending on what you are looking for.

You may also want to read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html) guide in the documentation to learn more about `UIStackViews`.

**How to use:**

Say you have two text fields, `textFieldA`, `textFieldB` and your separator view named `separatorView`.

Here is how you could do setup your `UIStackViews` programmatically inside your `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
   // Create and configure your stack view 

   let stackView   = UIStackView()
   stackView.axis  = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
   stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.fillProportionally
   stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
   stackView.spacing   = 20.0

   // Add your textfields and your separator view to the stack view

   stackView.addArrangedSubview(textFieldA)
   stackView.addArrangedSubview(separatorView)
   stackView.addArrangedSubview(textFieldB)

   stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   // Add your stack view:

   self.addSubview(stackView)

    // Configure the constraints for your stack view
    // (Of course you can set up your stack view the way you want and you don't have to absolutely use constraints, but it's just for the example)

    stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
```

It will save you a lot of time as you don't need to add constraints everywhere for all your views, but only for the stack view. The stack view will then take care of its arranged subviews.

One thing you may need in your case, is changing the hugging and compression resistance values for your views, to make sure it looks great on any screens.

As you can see you there are a lot of properties that you can set on your stack view, so just feel free to try different values and set it up the way you like!

Comment: self.rightAnchor, self.leftAnchor, self.topAnchor for these what can I give?

Comment: You can give it whatever value you want to give it, it depends on how much pixels do you need for your margins/etc, so this is completely up to you.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work as per your requirement ? Could you be more specific? I think you should not expect for an answer to give you a complete code with absolutely everything in it, but rather to give you hints, techniques, to show you how to approach a problem. Because all the values (spacing, left, right anchor constants, etc) really depends on your implementation and how you want your app to look like:). You can try playing with the values to see how it fits your problem, and of course please feel free asking me if something doesn't work as expected !

Comment: Thanks @Alex, but the problem is I am not using autolayout.

Comment: You're welcome! What do you mean you are not using auto layout ? How do you configure your views? :)

Comment: autoresizing using

Comment: Oh I see ! Do you have any specific reason to use Autoresizing instead of Autolayout inside your project ?

Comment: I dont have much knowledge on autolayout, thats the only reason, I know only basic autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use stack view with axis horizontal and distribution is equal to fillProportionally